# How to return the API response while using claudia-api-builder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, claudiajs, claudia.js

I am using Claudia-api-builder with Sequelize and facing issues while returning the response from an API

app.js :

```
const ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder');
const app = new ApiBuilder();

const citizenPersonalDetails = require('./app/controller/cont.citizenpersonaldetails');

app.get('/citizens', function (req, res) {
  citizenPersonalDetails.getAll(req, res);
})

module.exports = app
```

when I am returning the response like :

```
getAll: function (req, res) {
        citizenPersonalDetails.findAll({})
            .then(citizenPersonalDetails => {
                if (citizenPersonalDetails.length === 0) {
                    return res.status(200).json(citizenPersonalDetails)
                } else {
                    return res.status(200).json(citizenPersonalDetails)
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("==== ERROR ====", error);
            });
    }
```

This gives me error : res.status is not a function

In Claudia documentation, it mentions only the request object :

https://claudiajs.com/claudia-api-builder.html

from documentation :

```
var ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder'),
    api = new ApiBuilder(),
    superb = require('superb');

module.exports = api;

api.get('/greet', function (request) {
    return request.queryString.name + ' is ' + superb();
});
```

is there any response object for Claudia? what is the correct way to return the response?

I am using claudia-local-api to the APIS test locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `response` 2nd parameter (like you have in Express.js).

It appears that there is an [ApiResponse](https://github.com/claudiajs/claudia-api-builder/blob/master/docs/customise-responses.md#apiresponse-object) that you can use to return a custom response and customer header.

But if you already have this working using Express.js, maybe skip claudia-api-builder altogether and just use claudia to [run Express.js app in AWS Lambda](https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/serverless-express.html)